How to print multiple sheets in Excel to one pdf using VBA
I have this function that is called when I press a button in an Excel sheet. I have this code that works,(in code block below) but prints each sheet as a separate PDF file. I want to have all of these sheets in one singular PDF file.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim savePath As String
    

    ' Loop through all worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   
   If ws.Name = "IRP Records Review" Or ws.Name = "IRP SUMMARY" Or ws.Name = "IRP_1327-1328" Or ws.Name = "CORRESPONDENCE" Or ws.Name = "Opening Conference" Then
   ' change this to select each worksheet, then after selecting all the sheets print to pdf
   
    ' Define the path where you want to save the PDF
    savePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & ws.Name & ".pdf"
   
        ' Print each worksheet to PDF
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=savePath, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Else
        End If
    Next ws
    
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'Add a msgbox to let user know it's done
MsgBox ("The files were saved here: " & Application.DefaultFilePath)
End Sub


I have tried following multiple different tutorials, one of which was like this:
Sheets(Array("IRP Records Review", "IRP SUMMARY", "IRP_1327-1328", "CORRESPONDENCE", "Opening Conference")).Select ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\IRP_Review", _ openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
Which did not work. I kept getting the error "Runtime error ‘9’ Subscript out of range". Other variations on the code above did not work either.
I would like to rewrite this function in the code block,but make it to where all the sheets are in the same pdf. If anyone has any advice on what I should do please let me know. Thank you!

"Subscript out of range" - suggests that one or more of those sheet names are not correct.

^^^^^ Your code with correct names of sheets in the array works flawlessly.

@TimWilliams I have checked the names multiple times and they were all spelled correctly. Is there any other reason this error would be happening?

Which exact line gave you the error?  There are 2 lines there.  Try not using just Sheets(Array(<sheet names here>)).Select but be more specific like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(<sheet names here>).Select  If you still get the error then start with one sheet and add the other sheet names one at a time until you get the error.

Thank you for your help! I tried this again and tested each sheet individually, still did not work. But I solved it by doing the following (putting the name and index of each worksheet instead of their string names): Worksheets(Array(Worksheets(4).Name, Worksheets(5).Name, Worksheets(8).Name, Worksheets(9).Name)).Select    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=savePath, _    openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
